# How to share DLL with developers?

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I'm a graphic designer who is fairly new to XAML and blend. I've been reading a tutorial on Theming and It mentions about sharing DLL's with developers. It does not explain what specific Dll contains my resources to send to the developers. I've created a control library for my resources. Is there a specific Dll file that holds these resources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build a class library project it compiles a dll. Give them that dll
The file will be in bin/(debug or release)/[project].dll